# What seems to be wrong with my code? I'm running into a error

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

```
class Dog():
    def __int__(self,breed,name,spots):

        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
        self.spots = spots
my_dog = Dog(breed='lab',name='Sammy',spots='No Spots')
```

[image]

Comment: `__init__` not `__int__`

Comment: Please don't post images as text, please copy-past the text as text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `__int__` where you should have `__init__`

Answer (score -1):

```py
In [7]: class Dog():
   ...:     def __init__(self, breed, name, spots):
   ...:         self.breed = breed
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:         self.spots = spots
   ...:

In [8]: my_dog = Dog(breed='lab', name='Sammy', spots='No Spots')
```

`__init__` instead of `__int__`. Just change the value.

Comment: Why I get downvote for this answer? Any point?